# Issue with Spring setApplicationContext on official example

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to run one of `Spring's Getting Started guides` (using `Maven`) and I'm having issues with the `Produce a Web Service` one.

Link for the guide here https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

For some reason, I keep getting the error:

```
The method setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext) is undefined for the type MessageDispatcherServlet
```

on the following piece of code:

```
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }
```

I checked the API reference and `MessageDispatcherServlet` should inherit `setApplicationContext` from `FrameworkServlet`, but for some reason it isn't there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which Spring version are we talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have a wrong version of version of `spring-web` in your classpath. 
The method `setApplicationContext` is introduced in release 4.0.

See the official [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html#setApplicationContext-org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext-)

Comment: Thanks, that is correct. Can you please let me know what I should do to make it work with Spring 3?

Comment: You have to call `MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet(applicationContext);` i think.